# How to upload file to Sharepoint folder

Tags: python, sharepoint

I want to upload a file from my local machine to SharePoint using the `Office365-REST-Python-Client` library. The issue I'm having to uploading the file to a specific folder in SharePoint. Documentation seems to be all over the place. The Github repo provides the following solution to upload a file to the main "Documents" SP folder but what if I had subfolders like "Documents/Folder1"?

Here's the code to upload file to Documents in SharePoint:

```py
import os

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

path = "test_file.txt"
with open(path, 'rb') as content_file:
    file_content = content_file.read()

list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
name = os.path.basename(path)
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()
print("File has been uploaded to url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

I tried to change the `list_title` variable to `"Documents/Folder1"` but get the following error message as a result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py", line 80, in execute_query
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/a/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 953, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/companySite/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents%2FFolder1')/RootFolder/Files/add(overwrite=true,url='test_file.txt')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/example.py", line 27, in <module>
    target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()
  File "/Users/a/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_object.py", line 41, in execute_query
    self.context.execute_query()
  File "/Users/a/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_runtime_context.py", line 139, in execute_query
    self.pending_request().execute_query()
  File "/Users/a/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/office365/runtime/client_request.py", line 84, in execute_query
    raise ClientRequestException(*e.args, response=e.response)
office365.runtime.client_request_exception.ClientRequestException: ('-1, System.ArgumentException', "List 'Documents/Folder1' does not exist at site with URL 'https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/companySite'.", "404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/companySite/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents%2FFolder1')/RootFolder/Files/add(overwrite=true,url='test_file.txt')")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while I was looking for the exact same answer and having come to the same conclusions about the documentation needing to be a little more helpful.

I'm using an Azure Service Principal (Registered App) not username/password, that's the primary difference.

I store creds securely in Windows Credentials Manager using keyring.

So, in case you didn't figure it out yet, and for anyone else who finds your question, here's code that worked for me;

```
scriptName ='send_csv_to_spo.py'
import keyring #to access Windows Credentials Manager, where user/passwords are stored securely
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
import os #interact with OS for file actions
#Get creds from Windows Credentials Manager
appID = 'AppName' #Azure Registered App
clientId = '********-****-****-****-*************'
secret=keyring.get_password(appID,clientId)
sharepoint_url = f'https://*******.sharepoint.com'
siteName = f'/sites/*******'
target_url = f"folder/sub-folder"
site_url = sharepoint_url + siteName
#ensure file to send is in the same folder as this script
#call function from other script, passing the fileName
#eg:
#import send_csv_to_spo as sendFile #imports this file as module
#fileStr = 'test.csv' #test file in same folder
#sendFile.sendFileToSPO(fileStr) #calls function in module

def sendFileToSPO(fileName):
    #Authenticate using stored Azure App credentials
    from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(ClientCredential(clientId, secret))
    #Collect file for uploading
    with open(fileName, 'rb') as content_file:
        file_content = content_file.read()
    #Upload file to target url
    target_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(target_url)
    name = os.path.basename(fileName)
    target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()
    print("File has been uploaded as follows: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
    #File has been uploaded to url: /sites/******/******/******/testPush.csv
```